# Angular Bootstrap Modal binding issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I'm working with Angular Bootstrap and actually I'm trying to update correctly my model using a Modal.

Here is the very simple code:

controller:

```
function open(room) {
  var roomModal = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'room-modal.html',
    controller: 'RoomModalController',
    controllerAs: 'modal',
    resolve: {
      room: room
    }
  });

  roomModal.result.then(function (response) {
    RoomsService.update({
      roomId: response._id
    }, response).$promise (etc...);
  });
}
```

Modal Controller:

```
    var vm = this;

    vm.room = room;

    vm.save = function () {
      $uibModalInstance.close(vm.room);
    };

    vm.cancel = function () {
      $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
```

Basically I'm resolving the Room to get a few information about it and then if needed I wish to update a few information about the room within the modal.

It is working fine unless I do not want to update some information and I click "close".

What happen is: if I updated a few information and then I click "close" the information has not been updated on the database (OK) but has been updated in the main view... Because Angular bind the Modal information to the main view...

It is quite weird because I'm passing those information to a separate scope (vm) and unless I do not click save I should not expect this behavior...

What I'm doing wrong here?!?

Comment: If you are using binded data (`$scope.objname`) as `ng-models` on your inputs, these bindings are automatically changed upon value change. As far as i can see the `room` object is passed through your function callers which possibly uses the scope object. To prevent this you could create a seperate scope variable (to handle the change on manual action).

Comment: I'm using the `vm` format, not `$socpe`. Thanks

Comment: It's the same thing, instead of `$scope` your bindings object is just named `vm`. This does not change the digest cycle and binding methodology.

Comment: Can you please provide a solution? I don't understand what you mean... Thanks

Comment: Please provide a working sample through JSFiddle/... so we can help you out. It's impossible to help your specific problem by showing a solution.

Comment: Well, the `ng-models` are the one I'm passing from the `resolve` to show the current value. Then if I need to update one I do it otherwise not... It happen I update a value and then I decide to delete my changes, so I click "close". I expect it to be as it was before...

Comment: No need a fiddle probably... whole code is there and a modal with a simple input type text with a single field to update... If you wish I can update the question adding the HTML row... `<input type="text" ng-model="modal.room.number">` nothing more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `RoomModalController` deep copy the `room` object to prevent when updating that the model is also updated.

```
vm.room = angular.copy(room);
```

Now this object will take care of the modal binding, and will not interfere when changed to your root scope `vm.room` object.

To finalize saving this data, you have to save the `vm.root` modal object to your database, and also update the root scope `vm.room` object according these changes made in the modal.

Comment: Awesome, it helped me to understand it: `angular.copy` made the trick! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great it helped you out! :)